# getAssetFileDescriptor return null

Tags: android, android-assets, apk-expansion-files

I need to read files from an expansion file.
In the first LOG it shows expansionFile without problem.
But when i try to access the files inside zip file according with the [docs](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) the file returns null

```
ZipResourceFile expansionFile = null;
try {
    expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(context, 2, 1);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.d("DEBUG", expansionFile + "expansionFile");
AssetFileDescriptor fd = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("enterprise/config.json");
Log.d("DEBUG", fd + "FILE");
```

The zip file is organized like this

```
 /enterprie

     /0

     /config.json
```

Somebody know the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to change for this and work fine.

```
 InputStream is = expansionFile.getInputStream("enterprise/config.json");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems ZipResourceFile returns null for AssetFileDescriptor if the zip file is compressed. If you generate a non-compressed zip file using zip -gn an AssetFileDescriptor will be returned.

I didn't have much luck using this AssetFileDescriptor with BitmapFactory however, and was forced to use InputStreams.